# In what circumstances searchBar.text differ from searchText in this function?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
```

I put

```
NSAssert([searchBar.text isEqualToString:searchText],@"Search Bar Must Be The Same");
```

there and it doesn't seem to be violated

I just want to make sure because it's kind of strange.

Why bother having 2 parameters, searchBar and searchText if one of the parameter, namely searchText can be gotten simply by asking searchBar.text

Why not just have

```
-(void)searchBarTextDidChange:(UISearchBar *) searchBar
```

or
    -(void)textDidChangeForSearchBar:(UISearchBar *) searchBar

Doing it

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
```

implies that searchText carries essential information which mean that searchBar.text may differ from searchText. It never is. Unless of course you change things.

In fact, I suspected that searchText either points to searchBar.text or just a copy of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it's just a coding standard.

It's a good practice that the first argument of a delegate method should be the calling class

So `(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar` follows that.

Now if you omit `textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText` which can be retrieved from `searchBar.Text` 

then neither I nor Apple has found a good name for this method.

Comment: I updated the question. The NSAssert behaves as expected. It's just that why do we bother having 2 parameters if one is enough?

Comment: Also, it is more convenient and intuitive.

Comment: Hmmm.... Can you confirm that searchText will never differ from searchBar. The name of the function can be -(void)searchBarTextDidChange:(UISearchBar *) searchBar. It's like -(void)viewWillAppear

Comment: Once anyone can confirm that, which is the main purpose of this question, I'll just select the best answer. Looks like it's yours because no one else have better answers.

Comment: @SharenEayrs I don't think it will differ. and your method name `searchBarTextDidChange:` represents as the argument is text changed but its searchbar. So it's kinda ambitious.

Comment: oh first argument of a delegate should be the calling class.... Hmm... Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I also checked with all the possiblity. I think the only region for providing another parameter is to make consistency in these two functions

```
- (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text;
```

And

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
```

Comment: good enough. So does that mean searchText is effectively at least, a copy of searchBar.text?